# How to convert short text to datetime in access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I have a table whose column is of type short text that has data like the following example:

> 01/04/2014 10:45:47 p.m.

How can I convert to date/time?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
? CDate("01/04/2014 10:45:47 pm")
01.04.2014 22:45:47
```

German Access interprets it as German date format (dd.mm.yyyy), it will work according to your local settings.

All you have to do is to remove the dots:

```
? CDate(Replace("01/04/2014 10:45:47 p.m.", ".", ""))
```